# How to resize multiple videos inside nested folders using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, resizing

I'm trying to resize a bunch of videos down to a minimum width or height, depending on their aspect orientation, so if a video is 1920x1080 I want it scaled down to 960x540, but if it's 1080x1920 then the output should be 540x960.

My folder structure is something like:

root:
subfolder1:
file4
file5
subfolder2:
file6
file1
file2
file3

I've tried recursion with command line, but before checking if the basic idea works I ran in to a file error:

```
FOR /R %i in (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -i "%~f" -vf "scale='min(300,iw)':'min(300,ih)'" -preset veryfast "%~nf~tf" del /q "%~f"
```

I want the scaled files in the same directory as their inputs and the inputs must be removed when finished, but I don't know how to add simple affixes to file names so I went with what I found on google, namely adding a time stamp with `~tf`

When I run the line I get

```
%~f: No such file or directory
```

The bigger issue is that I'm not sure the conversion would keep the aspect ratio they way I stated (I don't want a 1000x600 video to be scaled down to 300x300, I want it scaled to 500x300 --- and a 600x1000 vid should scale down to 300x500, basically what the -resize "300x300^>" option would achieve in imagemagick)

I'm using cmd right now, but solutions in git bash or powershell are also welcome

edit: I forgot to mention that I need to also delete the input videos once the resizing is done

Comment: So you want to basically scale them down 2x? That's what all your examples are showing

Comment: not really that ratio is coincidental ... I want to resize them by their smaller dimension while keeping the aspect ratio, so a portrait video would have it's width scaled down to, say 450 while a landscape would have it's height scaled down to that, both keeping their aspects -- although scaling by their larger dimension instead of their smaller one would work too, I'm not picky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PowerShell command should work for you:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mp4 -Recurse | % { ffmpeg -i $_.FullName -vf "scale='if(gt(ih,iw),300,-2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),300,-2)'" "$($_.FullName)_scaled.mp4" }
```

The 1st part gets all the `.mp4` files in current directory and subdirs (`-Recurse`). Then it pipes all the results into `ForEach-Object` (`%`) and processes them with a chosen command.

The ffmpeg command takes the filename as input (`$_.FullName`), then applies a video filter than checks which dimension is bigger. If height (`ih`) is bigger than width (`iw`) then we scale down width to `300`, otherwise we preserve the aspect ratio and dimension divisible by 2 (`-2`). The 2nd condition is basically reversed. Lastly we save output as `[initial_name]_scaled.mp4`.

Comment: This seems to work for the files in the root folder but the videos in the nested subfolders don't get resized ... I get a ```<filename>.mp4 No such file or directory``` error for every file not at the top level of the directory structure... By the way would you happen to know to delete the source video after resizing?

Comment: I changed it to more reliable FullName property which includes full path. As for deleting, you should not ask additional unrelated questions under the same question, especially not without editing it. But `&& Remove-Item $_.FullName` inside the loop should just do the trick, at least in PS 7.

Comment: It kind of works now, but I'm getting ```height not divisible by 2``` errors and some files aren't getting processed. Would it have something to do with the ```-1``` value in the if statements? Should it be ```-2```?
> As for deleting, you should not ask additional unrelated questions under the same question, especially not without editing it
 -- Ah ok got it.

Comment: Hmm I don't really know what to look for so I can't really be specific (newbie to this stuff) but the encoding is h264 avc I think. Anyway, ```-2``` did it, I'm not getting any errors now. By the way thanks!

Comment: So all files got processed correctly now then? No problem

Comment: They did it works great now